# How to create correlated tables in a genomic database SQLite3

Tags: sqlite

I'm quite new to `sqlite3` but I want to use it for storing some genomic data I have, since manipulating from R takes a lot of time to process. I want to do some basic queries once the database is built, but my problem is, I don't know which tables I should create in order to make the appropriate queries.

This is how my big table looks like:

```
Chr Start   End Ref Alt Callers GATK_Illumina.counts    GATK_Illumina.samples   GATK_SOLiD.counts   GATK_SOLiD.samples  LIFE_SOLiD.counts   LIFE_SOLiD.samples  TVC_Ion.counts  TVC_Ion.samples Func.refGene    Gene.refGene
chr1    14948   14948   G   A   GATK_SOLiD  0.38    noSample    1.125   XK713   0.125   noSample    13.43   17E334|17E424|17H593|17J782|17J913|1B566    ncRNA_intronic;downstream   WASH7P;DDX11L1
chr1    14948   14948   G   A   TVC_Ion 0.38    noSample    1.125   XK713   0.125   noSample    13.43   17E334|17E424|17H593|17J782|17J913|1B566    ncRNA_intronic;downstream   WASH7P;DDX11L1
chr1    15820   15820   G   T   GATK_SOLiD  0.38    noSample    1.125   1E695   0.125   noSample    4.43    17E574|17H906|5K083B|6C418  ncRNA_exonic    WASH7P
chr1    15820   15820   G   T   TVC_Ion 0.38    noSample    1.125   1E695   0.125   noSample    4.43    17E574|17H906|5K083B|6C418  ncRNA_exonic    WASH7P
chr1    17452   17452   C   T   GATK_SOLiD  0.38    noSample    1.125   1H823   0.125   noSample    12.43   17G118|17G937|17H906|17J610|17M152|4E832|5C725|5F445|5F685|5H986|5J427  ncRNA_intronic;upstream WASH7P;MIR6859-1;MIR6859-2;MIR6859-3;MIR6859-4
chr1    17452   17452   C   T   TVC_Ion 0.38    noSample    1.125   1H823   0.125   noSample    12.43   17G118|17G937|17H906|17J610|17M152|4E832|5C725|5F445|5F685|5H986|5J427  ncRNA_intronic;upstream WASH7P;MIR6859-1;MIR6859-2;MIR6859-3;MIR6859-4
chr1    17538   17538   C   A   GATK_SOLiD  0.38    noSample    3.125   1E695|1H586|9J385   0.125   noSample    24.43   17C851B|17C918|17D521B|17E424|17F076    ncRNA_intronic;upstream WASH7P;MIR6859-1;MIR6859-2;MIR6859-3;MIR6859-4
chr1    17538   17538   C   A   TVC_Ion 0.38    noSample    3.125   1E695|1H586|9J385   0.125   noSample    24.43   17C851B|17C918|17D521B|17E424|17F076    ncRNA_intronic;upstream WASH7P;MIR6859-1;MIR6859-2;MIR6859-3;MIR6859-4
```

My queries are going to involve a search by `Chr`, `Start`, `End` to display which Callers have those coordinates, and also a search by gene. But my doubt is how to create the tables. I can create a table with `Chr Start End Ref Alt Callers` but how to link with another table having samples or genes? A coordinate (`Chr Start End`) can have multiple samples or callers linked.

Example of queries would be to type coordinates and display all info, and search by gene and show all the coordinates that include that gene

Basically I would like to know how many tables should I create and how to link them. I understand my coordinate table would be the parent table.

Which elements should be keys in the different tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about genomes, but based on the data and your description, this seems like a few 1:n relationships, and you are looking to create relational entities using primary/foreign keys. I'm not sure how familiar you are with SQL, you can take a look here for more on using it: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

You may want to create your tables like this, but further if there are additional 1:n or n:n relationships:

```
genes
gene_id, gene_name, data1, data2
// 1 gene -> many coords

gene_coords
gene_id, chr, start, end, data1, data2
// 1 coord -> many callers (and/or samples)

gene_callers // Are callers & samples 1:1?
gene_id, caller, sample
```

You can query the callers by using coordinates && chr with something like this:

```
SELECT gene_callers.callers FROM gene_callers
JOIN gene_coords ON gene_coords.gene_id = gene_callers.gene_id
WHERE gene_coords.start = 14948 AND gene_coords.end = 14948
AND gene_coords.chr = 'chr1';
```

I'm not sure if you would be querying multiple genes based on a coordinate range, if so then you may not want to be storing the start/end as same value, just store it as a coord and use BETWEEN on that field.  This query will also get you gene data for example.

```
SELECT gene.*, gene_callers.callers FROM gene_callers
JOIN gene ON gene.gene_id = gene_callers.gene_id
JOIN gene_coords ON gene_coords.gene_id = gene_callers.gene_id
WHERE gene_coords.coord BETWEEN 14948 AND 17538;
```

To get callers by gene name, you can do this:

```
SELECT gene_callers.callers FROM gene_callers
JOIN gene ON gene.gene_id = gene_callers.gene_id
WHERE gene.gene_name = 'a_gene';
```

You may need to tweak the join types based on any nulls and the dataset you're looking for.  You may need to create another table for samples if they are not 1:1 with callers.  Hopefully I interpreted your data correctly and this at least can point you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks a lot @Brandon G, and the callers:samples can be 1:n, the only unique is the sample_id, also I would like to have another table where sample:disease (1:n). Thanks for the sql manual, I have a couple of quick questions: when you create tables what do you refer to with `data1`, `data2`? and 2) in the first sql query `gene_chr` to what table belongs? I don't see any `chr` in `gene` table. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Oops, fixed that, meant gene_coords.chr.  data1/2 are just placeholder field names which can be anything in your dataset that is specific to a gene or gene coord or caller, etc...